# Grepping particular pattern and want to remove unwanted pattern using awk command

Tags: bash, awk, sh

I have one text file a.txt whose contents is shown below. I do not wanted to print "wide" as violation but it is showing up in the below command which I used. Can anybody help me on this so that "wide" will not come as violation.

Command used by me :

```
awk '{
  if ($0 =="") {rsave=0} 
  else {if (rsave==0) rule=$1; rsave=1};
  if ($0 ~ ":.* [1-9] violations? found")
    {printf "%s\n", $1; rsave=0} 
  else if ($0 ~ "[1-9] violations? found") 
    {printf "%s\n", rule; rsave=0}}' a.txt \
| sort -u
```

Output which is coming by using the above command:

```
DM5.S.7:IP_TIGHTEN_BOUNDARY  
DM6.S.7:IP_TIGHTEN_BOUNDARY  
text_net:text_short  
wide
```

Expected output:

```
DM5.S.7:IP_TIGHTEN_BOUNDARY  
DM6.S.7:IP_TIGHTEN_BOUNDARY  
text_net:text_short
```

a.txt file contents:

```
            ERROR SUMMARY

 DM5.S.7:IP_TIGHTEN_BOUNDARY : To avoid > 1.4 um x 
 1.4 um Metal empty space after IP abutment Metal 
 empty space must <= 0.7 um x 1.4 um on IP boundary 
 edge Metal empty space must <= 0.7 um x 0.7 um on 
 IP boundary corner
   contains ........................................... 1 violation found.             
   wide ............................................... 4 violations found.

 DM6.S.7:IP_TIGHTEN_BOUNDARY : To avoid > 1.4 um x 
 1.4 um Metal empty space after IP abutment Metal 
 empty space must <= 0.7 um x 1.4 um on IP boundary 
 edge Metal empty space must <= 0.7 um x 0.7 um on 
 IP boundary corner
   contains ........................................... 1 violation found.      
   wide ............................................... 4 violations found.

Violation   
  text_net:text_short ................................ 4 violations found.    
  text_abcd:text_short ................................ 0 violations found.
```

Comment: Why is `text_abcd:text_short` not in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it might be to pipe a `grep -v wide` after awk and after **sort**

From grep's manpage:

> v, --invert-match Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines. (-v is specified by POSIX .)

Comment: See this "wide" is something  I don't want. This name could be different in other files also. I want to grep only violation name like "DM5.S.7:IP_TIGHTEN_BOUNDARY" etc not wide as violation. There is a special case that when "Violation" word is coming , I need to grep "text_net:text_short"  as violation.

Comment: The -v is to ignore matching lines.